# Flask Return Redirect Doesn't Work in Python if Statement

Tags: python, html, flask, redirect, post

I have an if statement that checks if my Flask app has received a POST request. Inside the I statement, I want to redirect the user to another page of my flask app. This is the code I'm using:

```
@app.route('/convertingPlaylist', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def convertingPlaylist():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print("Done")
        return redirect('/redirect')
    else:
        executor.submit(main)
        return render_template('ConvertingPlaylist.html')
```

The else statement runs the `main` function and renders my HTML simultaneously and works fine. However, when I create a post, I can see the post worked because is see 'Done' printed in the terminal, but I don't get redirected to the `\redirect` page. Here is the `/redirect` page:

```
@app.route('/redirect', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def redirectPage():
    if request.form.get('Convert1') == 'Convert':
        return redirect('/convertingPlaylist')
    return render_template('HomePage.html')
```

Thanks to anyone who can help :)

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253033/discussion-on-question-by-matthew-flask-return-redirect-doesnt-work-in-python-i); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.